# How do I strip quotes from an input box using PHP?

Tags: php, replace, user-input, quotes

I have this:

```html
<input name="title" type="text" class="inputMedium" value="' . $inputData['title'] . '" />
```

I want to strip quotes from user input so that if someone enters something like:
"This is my title" it wont mess up my code.

I tried this and it's not working:

```
$inputData['title'] = str_replace('"', '', $_POST['title']);
```

Comment: Featured in *[Jeff Atwood: Stack Overflow - Building Social Software for the Anti Social](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcS7ECsA7cc)* at 13 min 25 secs. (Which also indicates the talk was probably about 10 years earlier than the publication date of 2020.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to remove `"` from `$inputData['title']`, so your HTML code is not messed up?

If so, the "right" solution is not to remove double-quotes, but to **escape** them before doing the actual output.

Considering you are generating HTML, **you should use the [`htmlspecialchars`][1] function**; this way, double-quotes *(and a couple of other characters)* will be encoded to HTML entities, and will not cause any trouble when injected into your HTML markup.

For instance:

```
echo '<input name="title" type="text" class="inputMedium" value="'
   . htmlspecialchars($inputData['title'])
   . '" />';
```

Note: depending on your situation *(especially, about the encoding/charset you might be using)*, you might to pass some additional parameters to `htmlspecialchars`.

Generally speaking, you should always escape the data you are sending as an output, not matter what kind of output format you have.

For instance:

- If you are generating some XML or HTML, you should use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)
- If you are generating some SQL, you should use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), or an equivalent, depending on the type of database you're working with

Comment: Just noticed: one could use single quotes instead of double quotes in the input html (like <input value='hello'/>). But since htmlspecialchars leaves single quotes alone, this might be a security hole?

Answer (score 2):

User input should be run through `htmlspecialchars()` to be used in this sort of case.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend you to use **htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES)** before displaying anything user generated anywhere...

Comment: htmlentities hasnt work for me, only htmlspecialchars() did. The problem was that for some reason htmlentities would not handle accent correctly